# Google public calendar API returns error 401 login required when adding an event

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-calendar-api

I want to insert an event in one of my public calendars using the following code, But it returns error 401 login required

I am getting Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token error while insert events. Where I am doing wrong ?

Here is my code

````
      var mykey = "MY API KEY";
      var calendarid = "MY CALENDAR ID LIKE XXXXXX@group.calendar.google.com";
      var event = {
        summary: "Google I/O 2015",
        location: "800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103",
        description: "Heyyyyyy",
        start: {
          dateTime: "2021-02-16T09:00:00-07:00",
          timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles",
        },
        end: {
          dateTime: "2021-02-17T17:00:00-07:00",
          timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles",
        },
        recurrence: ["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"],
        attendees: [
          { email: "lpage@example.com" },
          { email: "sbrin@example.com" },
        ],
        reminders: {
          useDefault: false,
          overrides: [
            { method: "email", minutes: 24 * 60 },
            { method: "popup", minutes: 10 },
          ],
        },
      };

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: encodeURI(
          "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/" +
            calendarid +
            "/events/?key=" +
            mykey
        ),
        dataType: "json",
        data: event,
        success: function (response) {
          //do whatever you want with each
        },
        error: function (response) {
          //tell that an error has occurred
        },
      });```

Get API is working fine, but I am getting above error with post API.

I do not know whY I am getting this error. Can anyone help me ? What is the issue ?
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation for [events insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) you will find that this method requires that you be authenticated with one of the following scopes

[image]

You appear to be missing the Oauth2 section. YOu cant just use an API key api keys only give you access to public data you need to use Oauth2 to authorize a user

```
 /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        }, function(error) {
          appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
        });
      }
```

I recommend looking into the [Google calendar api quickstart for javascript.](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js)

Note: API keys only give you access to read even if the calendar is public you still need to use Oauth2 and authorize a user in order to write to the calendar.

Comment: Hi. Thanks For quick reply. I understood. But what if I want to allow any other person to add events in my calendar means any other person can subscribe to my public calendar. How I can achieve this ?

Comment: If you have gsuite then you can create a service account and have that do the inserts for you.   Without gsuite you will need to use Oauth2 authentication as a user storing the refresh token and using that to authenticate in the future.   However neither of those options will work with Javascript you will need to  use a server sided programming language.    I guess what i am saying is you cant achieve that with Javascript.